# Integrating $\iint_R \sin(9x^2+4y^2)\ dA$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The question I'm trying to solve is: $\displaystyle \iint_R \sin(9x^2+4y^2)dA$, where $R$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by $9x^2+4y^2=1$.

I'm a little confused in solving this. Does this mean that I can solve this by  $\displaystyle\int_0^3 \int_0^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin(1)\ dy\,dx$? Then I would get  $\frac{9}{2}\sin(1)$.. but this is a 12 point question and I'm not sure if this is supposed to be this easy...

Comment: You can't do like this. Means direct substitution, that to inside the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

(What Robert Israel is indicating to)

$ (3x)^2+(2y)^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

We have done change of variable.

What is the region of integration $R$ in the $ab$-plane,? Which we will call $S$

So using Jacobian:

$\frac{\partial (a,b)}{\partial (x,y)} = \begin{vmatrix}
    3 & 0  \\ 
    0 & 2  \\ 
    \notag
    \end{vmatrix}
    = 6$

Therefore the region of integration  $S$ is bounded by the part of the unit circle $a^2+b^2 =1$ so lies in the first quadrant of the ab -plane.

$\large\int \int_R \sin(9x^2+4y^2)dydx=\frac{1}{6}\int \int_S \sin(a^2+b^2)dydx$

Then using Polar coordinate solve the problem.

i.e $dA = rdrd\theta$,   $\hspace{1cm}r^2 = a^2+b^2$.

Comment: ohhh so the equation changes to $ \frac{1}{6}  \int_0^{\frac{ \pi }{2}} \int_0^1 r\sin(r^2)dr d\theta$? But why is this divided by 6?

Comment: @user125342, Yup. i.e. because of the fact of transformation(Jacobian factor).

Comment: ok... i have no idea what jacobian factor is... i'll go study that now. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user125342, Ok you can do that. You can see this also [Jacobian transformation](http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/soton/HELM/workbooks/workbook_27/27_4_changing_coords.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

No, $9 x^2 + 4 y^2 \le 1$ in your region, not $=$.  And I have no idea where you got your upper limits for $x$ and $y$.

Hint: first take the change of variables $x = u/3$, $y = v/2$, so your region becomes a circular quadrant.  Then use polar coordinates.